# SQL update query VB ASP

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I'm trying to do an update query in SQL Server database, through VB with ASP.net

This bit of code below updates all records with the same value. I want it to update just one record, depending on the "email" session variable.

```vb
Dim cmdstring As String = "UPDATE [Customer] SET card_type=@CARDTYPE"

    Email = Session("email")
    ', Card_Number, Expiry_Date, Security_Number, Name_On_Card) Values (@CARDTYPE, @CARDNUMBER, @EXPIRYDATE, @SECURITYNUMBER, @NAMEONCARD)"

    conn = New SqlConnection("data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\UniversityClothing.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
    cmd = New SqlCommand(cmdstring, conn)

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CARDTYPE", cardtype)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CARDNUMBER", cardnumber)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EXPIRYDATE", expirydate)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SECURITYNUMBER", securitynumber)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAMEONCARD", nameoncard)

    conn.Open()

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    conn.Close()
```

Comment: Has customer got an email column? If so, add a WHERE statement.

Comment: Yes but the WHERE statement won't work, such a newbie!

Comment: How do you mean won't work? Do you get an error message? If so, what is it? What was the statement that you tried?

Comment: Dim cmdstring As String = "UPDATE [Customer] SET card_type=@CARDTYPE WHERE email=?"

Comment: So where are your parameters? Also, best not mix and match. WHERE email=@Email

Comment: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?" , session("email"))

Comment: syntax error at question mark

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```vb
Using conn As New SqlConnection("data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\UniversityClothing.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"), _
      cmd As New SqlCommand("UPDATE [Customer] SET card_type=@CARDTYPE WHERE email = @Email", conn)

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CARDTYPE", cardtype)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Session("email"))

    conn.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

Also note that I really don't like the AddWithValue() method. It can lead to serious performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a WHERE clause.  Example:

```
Dim cmdstring As String = "UPDATE [Customer] SET card_type=@CARDTYPE, Card_Number=@CARDNUMBER, Expiry_Date=@EXPIRYDATE, Security_Number=@SECURITYNUMBER, Name_On_Card=@NAMEONCARD WHERE Email=@EMAIL)"
Email = Session("email")

conn = New SqlConnection("data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\UniversityClothing.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
cmd = New SqlCommand(cmdstring, conn)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CARDTYPE", cardtype)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CARDNUMBER", cardnumber)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EXPIRYDATE", expirydate)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SECURITYNUMBER", securitynumber)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAMEONCARD", nameoncard)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMAIL", Email)

conn.Open()

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

conn.Close()
```

NOTE THE FOLLOWING:

1. Per PCI regulation, you should not store security number, and should
   do appropriate encryption for your card number
2. I assume you have validated all the fields to prevent SQL injection

Comment: Incorrect syntax near ')'. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Source Error: 


Line 479:        conn.Open()
Line 480:
Line 481:        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Line 482:
Line 483:        conn.Close()

Comment: This is the error message i am receiving after your code suggestion, any thoughts?

Comment: Remove the ')' from the end of the cmdstring